# What's causing my Tkinter interface errors?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My authentication system to log in or validate credentials (as well as things like checking strength of password) has a Tkinter greeting screen with two radio buttons:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
global UserDataTuple
global cursor
root=tk.Tk()
TimeslotOrShop=tk.Frame()

def Timeslot():
    print("Book a timeslot here.")

def Shop():
    print("Shop here.")

def TimeslotOrShop():
    TimeslotOrShop=input("Would you like to book a timeslot or shop?: ")
    if TimeslotOrShop == "Timeslot":
        Timeslot()
    if TimeslotOrShop == "Shop":
        Shop()

def InsertDetailsIntoSystem(First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('GUISHOP Login System.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

        sqlite_insert_with_param = "INSERT INTO UserDetails (First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
        UserDataTuple = [First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password]
        
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, UserDataTuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("You are now signed up to the system.")
        TimeslotOrShop()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Sorry, we were unable to insert your data into our system", error)

def AuthenticatingDetailsUsingDatabase(NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Password):
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('GUISHOP Login System.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    DataRetrievalStatement=f"SELECT First_Name AND Last_Name from UserDetails WHERE NHSNumber='{NHSNumber}' AND DateOfBirth='{DateOfBirth}' AND Password='{Password}';"
    cursor.execute(DataRetrievalStatement)
    if not cursor.fetchone():
        print("Sorry, these details are invalid.")
        authentication()
    else:
        print("Your details have been validified; welcome back to the system!")
        TimeslotOrShop()


def registration():
        print("Please input your details into our system.")
        First_Name=input("What is your first name?: ")
        Last_Name=input("What is your last name?: ")
        NHSNumber=input("What is your NHS number? (should be 6 digits): ")
        DateOfBirth=input("What is your date of birth? (In DD/MM/YYYY format): ")
        Email=input("What is your email address?: ")
        Password=str(input("What would you like your password to be?: "))
        while len(Password)<8:
            Password=input("Your password must contain at least 8 characters. Please input a new password: ")
        else:
            UserDataTuple = [First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password]
            InsertDetailsIntoSystem(First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password)

def authentication():
    print("Welcome back! Please input your details below.")
    NHSNumber=input("What is your NHS Number? (should be 6 digits): ")
    DateOfBirth=input("What is your date of birth? (In DD/MM/YY format): ")
    Password=input("What is your password?: ")
    AuthenticatingDetailsUsingDatabase(NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Password)


widget=Label(root, text="Welcome to GUISHOP! Are you a new or returning user?: ")
widget.pack()
Button=tk.Button(root, text="New", command=registration).pack(side=LEFT)
Button=tk.Button(root, text="Returning", command=authentication).pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
    
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Things started to go wrong when I tried a more complex Tkinter interface with multiple frames within the same interface (going to a new frame would be triggered by the press of a radio button):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
global UserDataTuple
global cursor
root=tk.Tk()

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
  
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  
        self.frames = {} 
  
        for F in (WelcomePage, Registration, Authentication):
  
            frame = F(container, self)
  
            self.frames[F] = frame
  
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
  
        self.show_frame(WelcomePage)
  

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def Timeslot():
    print("Book a timeslot here.")

def Shop():
    print("Shop here.")

def TimeslotOrShop():
    TimeslotOrShop=input("Would you like to book a timeslot or shop?: ")
    if TimeslotOrShop == "Timeslot":
        Timeslot()
    if TimeslotOrShop == "Shop":
        Shop()

def InsertDetailsIntoSystem(First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('GUISHOP Login System.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

        sqlite_insert_with_param = "INSERT INTO UserDetails (First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
        UserDataTuple = [First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password]
        
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, UserDataTuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("You are now signed up to the system.")
        TimeslotOrShop()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Sorry, we were unable to insert your data into our system", error)

def AuthenticatingDetailsUsingDatabase(NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Password):
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('GUISHOP Login System.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    DataRetrievalStatement=f"SELECT First_Name AND Last_Name from UserDetails WHERE NHSNumber='{NHSNumber}' AND DateOfBirth='{DateOfBirth}' AND Password='{Password}';"
    cursor.execute(DataRetrievalStatement)
    if not cursor.fetchone():
        print("Sorry, these details are invalid.")
        authentication()
    else:
        print("Your details have been validified; welcome back to the system!")
        TimeslotOrShop()


class Registration(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            Registration.pack = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
            Registration.pack()
            
            Input = ttk.Label(self, text="Please input your details into our system.")
            Input.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
            Registration.create_window(200, 25, window=Input)

            FirstNameInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your first name?: ")
            FirstNameInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=FirstNameInput)
            
            First_Name=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200, 140, window=First_Name)

            LastNameInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your last name?: ")
            LastNameInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=LastNameInput)

            Last_Name=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200,140, window=Last_Name)

            NHSNumberInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your NHS Number? (should be 6 digits): ")
            NHSNumberInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=NHSNumberInput)
            
            NHSNumber=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200, 140, window=NHSNumber)

            DOBInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your date of birth? (In DD/MM/YY format): ")
            DOBInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=DOBInput)
            
            DateOfBirth=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200, 140, window=DateOfBirth)

            EmailInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your email address?: ")
            EmailInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=EmailInput)

            Email=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=Email)
            
            PasswordInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your password?: ")
            PasswordInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
            Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=PasswordInput)
            
            Password=tk.Entry(self)
            Registration.create_window(200, 140, window=Password)
            while len(Password)<8:
                PasswordNotLongEnough = tk.Label(self, text="Your password must contain at least 8 characters. Please input a new password: ")
                PasswordNotLongEnough.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
                Registration.create_window(200, 100, window=PasswordNotLongEnough)
                
                Password=tk.Entry(self)
                Registration.create_window(200, 140, window=Password)
            else:
                UserDataTuple = [First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password]
                InsertDetailsIntoSystem(First_Name, Last_Name, NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Email, Password)

class Authentication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        Authentication.pack = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
        Authentication.pack()
        
        WelcomeBack = ttk.Label(self, text="Welcome back! Please input your details below.")
        WelcomeBack.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
        Authentication.create_window(200, 25, window=WelcomeBack)

        NHSNumberInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your NHS Number? (should be 6 digits): ")
        NHSNumberInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
        Authentication.create_window(200, 100, window=NHSNumberInput)
        
        NHSNumber=tk.Entry(self)
        Authentication.create_window(200, 140, window=NHSNumber)

        DOBInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your date of birth? (In DD/MM/YY format): ")
        DOBInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
        Authentication.create_window(200, 100, window=DOBInput)
        
        DateOfBirth=tk.Entry(self)
        Authentication.create_window(200, 140, window=DateOfBirth)

        PasswordInput = tk.Label(self, text="What is your password?: ")
        PasswordInput.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
        Authentication.create_window(200, 100, window=PasswordInput)
        
        Password=tk.Entry(self)
        Authentication.create_window(200, 140, window=Password)
        
        AuthenticatingDetailsUsingDatabase(NHSNumber, DateOfBirth, Password)

class WelcomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        widget=Label(self, text="Welcome to GUISHOP! Are you a new or returning user?: ")
        widget.pack()
        Button=tk.Button(self, text="New", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Registration)).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button=tk.Button(self, text="Returning", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Authentication)).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.mainloop()
    
app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Tkinter simply displays 2 completely empty windows. When I close them, the following error code comes up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Matthew
> Newman\Documents\Tester Code\GUISHOP Tkinter Test.py", line 183, in
>
> app = tkinterApp()   File "C:\Users\Matthew Newman\Documents\Tester Code\GUISHOP Tkinter Test.py", line 27, in
> **init**
> frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")   File "C:\Users\Matthew
> Newman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 2493, in grid_configure
> self.tk.call(
> _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "grid" command: application has been destroyed

The code is incomplete (hence why it doesn't do anything after a certain point and why some radio buttons are missing). What's causing my errors? Code is Python 3.9.

Comment: You should not execute `self.mainloop()` inside `WelcomePage.__init__()`.  It will block the execution of other code followed until both windows, `root` and `app`, are closed.  When both windows are closed, the application proceeds to create instance of `Registration` frame which raises the exception.  Why do you create two instances of `Tk()`?

Comment: Thanks very much for your input! Out of interest, what do you mean by two instances of Tk()? (Sorry, I'm not an expert at programming...)

Comment: The two instances of `Tk()` are `root` and `app`.

Comment: I just ran the code you said about, and the Welcome Page ran perfectly; thank you!  I seem to be encountering new problems, however... I'll see about solving what you said to do with the instances.

Comment: There are still other issues in your code.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are some of the issues you notice, as I'll admit that I'm struggling a little to pinpoint some of them on my own? Sorry to keep asking questions, I'm just a bit stuck.

Comment: Your while loop to check the password will occur when the App first opens and block the application's event loop. Consider putting this code inside a function that is called when a new character is entered in to the text box and remove the while loop so that the code to evaluate the length of the password is evaluated once.

Comment: Also `AuthenticatingDetailsUsingDatabase` will be called when the app first opens rather than when a button is pressed.